How to Fetch a User's Guild-Specific Banner Using the Discord API?
I want to fetch the guild-specific banner of a user using the Discord API. While I have found out how to get the normal banner of a user, I haven't found a way to fetch the guild-specific banner from a custom server profile.
Since there is a way to get the guild avatar and even the guild avatar decorations, I am really confused about why I cannot find a way to get the guild-specific banner.
To clarify, I am NOT looking for the banner available via https://cdn.discordapp.com/banners/{USER_ID}/{banner_hash}.png?size=512 but rather the guild-specific banner from the custom server profile.
Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to achieve it using the Discord API?
